# Working with Raspberry PI GPIO - Do I want a virtual / abstract / interface class?

Tags: c++, class, raspberry-pi, gpio

## Intro

I am doing some work with Raspberry PI GPIO. Until now I was writing code as you would in C, using functions to group together sections of code.

My work has got to the point where I am happy that everything is working, but now things are starting to get messy and so I would like to move towards an object oriented approach.

## Problem

Here is the problem I face.

At the moment I have a class which represents my "device". (The hardware I built which is attached to the GPIO port.) The hardware has 2 distinct sections. One section is an "input" section, and the other is an "output" section.

To help you understand this better, the "input" section is an ADC. (Analog-to-digital converter.) This is a device which converts an analog signal to a 10bit binary representation. (In case you were not familiar with electronics.)

The "output" section is just a transistor which switches a set of LEDs on and off.

I wanted to have a class which represented the ADC Board, and one which represented the LED Board, as they are 2 conceptually different devices, as they are not "linked" in any way.

This causes a problem, as the GPIO pins must be set to certain values before their modes are set. By values I mean "HIGH" or "LOW", 1 or 0. By modes I mean "INPUT" or "OUTPUT". This sounds strange, but basically, the ADC will become de-synchronized if the control lines are not set to their correct LOGIC HIGH and LOGIC LOW values before it is powered up. (This is a very strange device, it does not power up until it is told to, even though it is connected to power. (VCC or VDD 5.0V) One of the control lines sends a signal to power up the device.

In order to carry out the above, consider that the GPIO pins are initially in INPUT mode. To "make the ADC work properly" we first set the data values (HIGH / LOW) which are to be present on the pins BEFORE they are changed to OUTPUT mode. This way, when the mode is changed from INPUT to OUTPUT the data is present which the correct values, and we won't upset the ADC.

My initial idea was to have a constructor for the ADC which firstly sets the values for output data and then changes the requires pins from INPUT mode to OUTPUT mode. But this forces us to construct the ADC Board class before the LED Board class.

This can be fixed by both constructors carrying out the same code to set the output modes, but this seems like a bad idea because we are calling 2 bits of code twice - not a very elegant solution.

Another solution is to have a GPIOPort class which combines the input and output devices together, but this isn't very elegant either and it would be difficult to modify if we were to ever add a second, identical, LED Board. (For example.)

## What I think I want but I'm not sure...

I think what I want is another class which represents the GPIOPort itself. (A kind of abstract idea, I guess?) Then I think I want "a class within a class" to represent the ADC Board and "a class within a class" to represent the LED Board, also. I can't remember what this technique is called, but usually the "outer class" is like a shell, with a pointer to an object of the type which is the "inner class" and a create method and a destroy method. The outer class does something like `pointer = new type;` in the create method and `delete pointer` in the destroy method. This allows the constructor to be called when required, and the class destructor to be called when required.

The point of this is that the GPIOPort class constructor handles the order in which these objects are created, which hides everything from main(). Within main, the programmer just does something like `GPIOPort myGPIOPort;`, and this handles everything you need, so you don't have to include 20 lines of code in main() to setup the data for the output pins, which is the only other solution. (Which I didn't mention above.)

## Questions

So my first question is what is this technique known as? I thought it was called a wrapper class, but my understanding is a wrapper class is for using fundamental types like `double` and `int` as objects. (And adding methods like `clear()` or `reset()` or something like that.) Is this what I actually want to be doing, or is there a better method? (I guess it comes down to "how do I fix my problem".)

My second question is that, as far as I can remember, I have to make some of the methods (the destructor?) virtual methods, but I can't remember why. (Or perhaps I don't, and I'm just confused.)

My third question is are there any examples of this which I can use to help myself understand it, or alternatively, where can I go to improve my understanding. (Resources.)

Thanks, obviously this is quite a long question. I tried to include as much information as I could to help explain the situation. If you want clarification, then I'll try and improve what I said.

## Edit: More info on devices

The data must be sent to the GPIO pins before their mode is changed from input to output.

The GPIO pins look like all zeros, as there are pull-down resistors on the pins, and they are still set as inputs. The data which as been sent does not appear until their mode is changed.

The pins are then set to output mode. (Or some of them are anyway.) Now the data which was sent appears on the pins.

If the pins are set to output mode before the data is sent, we cannot prevent the ADC from powering up, as the data pin which controls the powering up of the ADC may be set to HIGH. It may be set to LOW, but there is no way of telling, its state is undefined, until we tell the GPIO what values we want before setting the mode to output. Luckily, we can guarantee that all the pins will be in input mode.

Comment: Why not simply set every pins to what you want (OUTPUT / INPUT) in the `LED Board class` and in the `ADC` class, save the current pin states, update the level of the pins you want, start the ADC, and restore the previous states?

Comment: @Holt I don't think I explained the problem very well because what you said doesn't parallel with what I was trying to say, I will add some more info.

Comment: Maybe it's just me that misunderstood something. I you could add a small list with each step ordered, it would help I think.

Comment: @Holt good idea, is what I have added helpful?

Comment: Yes I think. If I understood your problem, you need to set some values (high/low) on the GPIO (like 0101) to power up the ADC? But if you put the pins in output mode with bad values (like 0010), it will upset the ADC? So you need to set the GPIO values and then put all pins in OUTPUT mode?

Comment: @Holt Yes, that's basically it. The question is then, "how do I do this in an object oriented approach, where the setup of the pins is done _absolutly_ _first_ (ie: in a constructor of a class) regardless of which class I create first." - Obviously that isn't possibly unless I have duplicate code, and so I want both the LED Board and ADC Board classes to be created by another class, the GPIOPort class. Everything should be controlled through that one class.

Comment: Could you add some information on the pin connection between the Raspberry Pi, your ADC and your LED Board? And what exactly you need to set on which port to power up the ADC. Maybe a link to the ADC / LED Board references could help!

Comment: @Holt Yeah sure, the exact device is AD7813. The requirements for this device are that the CONVST pin is logic low when VDD is applied. (Or in this case that this pin is an input.) Following this, the requirement is that CS, RD are set to logic high before the pinmode for these data lines are set to output. Then CONVST must be set to logic low before the pinmode is set to output for this data line.

The data sheet is not well written in my opinion. It took me a while to understand it fully.

The LED Board hasn't had the hardware for it created yet. I'm still working on that.

Comment: What are the pins shared by the AD7813 and your LED Board? If there are no pins shared, I don't see why there is a problem in the initialization?

Comment: @Holt This is true, but creating seperate LED and ADC Board classes would force us to setup pin modes in 2 separate places (their constructors). I thought this wasn't ideal, as it would be preferable to setup *all the pins at once*, *all in the same place*. This was why I started thinking about having a GPIOPort class which would construct, and setup all the pins in the one constructor, at one time.

Comment: I think that's normal to setup the pins used by the ADC in the ADC constructor, and the pins used by the LED board in the LEDBoard constructor, these are 2 totally separated devices in fact if I understood?

Comment: @Holt Yes, I guess that is true, but when I was thinking about it earlier I just didn't like splitting the code in that way. I guess there's nothing really wrong with that though?

Comment: No, and I think it's even better this way, you separate what should be separated. My answer (and the 2 others) supposed that you add only one big "device" or "board" that contains ADC and LED, so that's what we tried to answer to.

Answer (score 3):

Some definitions:

- Device: The entire device that is attached to the GPIO (Input and Output)
- LEDBoard: The output parts of a Device
- ADCBoard: The input parts of a Device

I highly recomment to **not** use a singleton. Some day you may connect a second device to other GPIO Pins and you will be in trouble.

If you create separate classes for LEDBoard and ADCBoard, you have to ask: 
"What do I need to create a LEDBoard/ADCBoard?"
Well... You need a Device!

So my design would be the following:

```
struct DeviceDescriptor
{
  int portNumber;
  // add additional variables to identify the device
}

class Device
{
  Device(DeviceDescriptor descriptor)
  {
    //Insert your initialization...
    //You can maintain a static vector of already opened Devices to throw an
    //error if an allready opened device is reopened
  }
  ~Device()
  {
    //Deinit device
  }

  // A device should not be copyable
  Device(const& Device) = delete;
  //TODO do the same for copy assignment
  //TODO implement move ctr and move assignment operator

  //TODO add needed mamber variables
}

class LEDBoard
{
  LEDBoard(std::shared_ptr<Device> device) : m_device(device)
  {
    //Do init stuff
  }

  //Your functions

  private:
  std::shared_ptr<Device> m_device;
}

 //ADCBoard is analog to LEDBoard
```

You can use the classes like this:

```
int main(void)
{
   auto device = std::make_shared<Device>(DeviceDescriptor());
   LEDBoard led1(device);
   ADCBoard adc1(device);
   //Your stuff...
}
```

Benefits:

- You can have multiple Devices
- More LEDBoards can be added easily
- By the use of shared_ptr, the device object will be destoryed when the last LEDBoard/ADCBoard is destroyed

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I make a big edit of this post, because I think that's currently not the best solution. This edit is really similar to @MarkusMayer answer, but I came to it in a very different way of thinking (I think), so maybe it will help you.

First, let define a GPIO pin, which can be anything you want (a class would be good, then you can do `pin.setOutput()` or `pin.set()`, etc. I let you define it the way you want, let's just assume we have a `GPIOPin` class.

First, I define an abstract board as a set of pin, which look quite correct to me:

```
template <int N>
class Board {
protected:
    Board (std::array <GPIOPin, N> const& pins) : _pins(pins) { }
    std::array <GPIOPin, N> _pins ;
};
```

Then I define interface for `ADC` and `LEDs` which are also abstract:

```
class ADC {
public:
    ADC () { }
    float read () { }
} ;

class LEDs {
public:
    LEDs () { }
    void set (int) { }
} ;
```

Now I can create what represent the real board with `ADC` and `LED`:

```
class MyBoard : public Board <5> { // Let's assume it's connect to 5 bits
public:
    MyBoard (std::array <GPIOPin, N> const& pins) : Board<5>(pins) {
        // Here you can initialize what you want
    }
} ;
```

Then you create your own `ADC` and `LED`:

```
class AD7813 : public ADC {
    Board <5> _board ;
public:
    AD7813 (Board <5> *board) : ADC(), _board(board) { }
} ;

// Same for the LED
```

Finally, you can simply use it as follow:

```
Board <5> *board = new MyBoard(/* The corresponding GPIO pins. */) ;
ADC *adc = new AD7813(board) ;
LEDs *led = new MyLEDs(board) ;
```

I did not define destructor for `MyBoard` or `Board` but of course you can. You can also use `shared_ptr` like @MarkusMayer.

**End of edit.**

I think there are different approaches to this problem, I'll present here what I would have done. It is often difficult to use OO design on embedded system, first thing is that you should have singleton class almost everywhere because you've only one `ADC` (you cannot instanciate multiple ADC), so your ADC class (and LEDBoard class) should look like:

```
class ADC {
public:
    static ADC *getInstance () {
        if (_instance == nullptr) {
            _instance = new ADC () ;
        }
        return _instance ;
    }
private:
    ADC () ;
};
```

To answer your problem, I would create a base class that do your initialization, and will do it only once (use of a static member to know if ports are already initialized).

```
class GPIOs {
protected:
    GPIOs () {
        if (!GPIOs::_init) {
            /* Do what you want. */
            GPIOs::_init = true ;
        }
    }
private:
    static bool _init ;
} ;

bool GPIOs::_init = false ;
```

Then your `ADC` and `LEDBoard` class inherit from `GPIOs`:

```
class ADC : public GPIOs {
public:
    ADC *getInstance () { /* ... */ }
private:
    ADC () : GPIOs () { } // Call constructor
} ;
```

Then in your code, you simply do:

```
ADC *adc = ADC::getInstance () ;
```

You could also use a singleton for the `GPIOs` class but since it's an abstract class than is only used by `ADC` and `LEDBoard` which are already singleton, it's not the most useful.

I'm sure there are plenty of other ways to deal with your problem, but the main idea I wanted to show is the use of `init` method / class that you can call multiple time without doing mutiple initialization because of the `_init` boolean.

Comment: Ah yeah, thanks, I can see how this would be useful for preventing 2 instances of the GPIO class appearing. I will defiantly use it, but there are still some questions to be answered yet. Thanks for your help, the solution will probably contain contributions from several people.

Comment: Should bool _init be static?

Answer (score 0):

I'll sketch you an idea. I don't know of any design patterns for this, but the below may fit your need.

Firstly I agree with your idea of using a GPIOPort to control the whole port, but I want to introduce a more modular approach than a "class in a class". Instead of setting up the ports in the device constructor, I suggest creating an object that describes the device, and let GPIOPort setup the devices based on these descriptors.

My idea is to encapsulate the access to the GPIO through the GPIOPort class. But, leave the raw output open for the user of the code to work with. This could be combined with other classes as well, but they should be *using* `GPIOPort` in this design, and not the other way around.

One (of many, sometimes conflicting) advices in OOP is that you should only subtype a class if its behaviour has changed. If you can express difference between two classes simply by changing the attributes, they are of the same class. I'm unsure if that is the case here, depending on how how much work you have to do to initialize a device.

```
using ports = uint64_t; // some suitable unsigned bit-maskable type.

// Used to control the IO.
struct DeviceDescriptor {
    ports    in_mask,  // Which pins does this device use for input
             out_mask, // Which pins does this device use for output
             init,     // Initial state of the pins.
             shutdown; // State to send when device should power down.
};

class GPIOPort {
    static const ports ALL_PORTS = ~static_cast<ports>(0);
    std::vector<Device> devices; 
public:
    // Initialize the devices.
    GPIOPort( std::vector<Device> & devices ) : devices(devices) { 
        ports used_ports = 0, init = 0;
        for ( auto & device : devices ) {
              init |= device.init;

              // Assert no overlapping ports
              ports partition = device.init | device.in_mask | device.out_mask | device.shutdown;
              if ( used_ports & partition){
                 // Signal overlapping ports.
              } else {
                 used_bits |= current;
              }
          }
          set_bits(init, ALL_PORTS); // Actually sets the output.
      }

      // Read the input of device number 'dev'
      ports read_state( int dev, ports mask = ALL_PORTS ) {
          return read_bits( devices.at(dev).input_mask & mask );
      }

      // etc...

      ~GPIOPort() {
           ports shutdown;
           for ( auto & device : devices ) {
              shutdown |= device.shutdown;
           }
           set_bits(shutdown, ALL_PORTS);
      }
};
```

Comment: Is `using ports = uint64_t` the same as `typedef ports uint64_t`? -- or should that be `typedef uint64_t ports` -- I forget which way round it is.

Comment: It's the same thing, `using` in this context is C++11 and also works as a template: `template<class T> using two_of_a_kind = std::pair<T, T>`